# Deep Copying of Model with Instance of a Model which contains an instance of the base Model. StackOverflow Exception

Tags: c#, recursion, stack-overflow, deep-copy

Okay, To preface this question, here are a few things.

1. The solution cannot use Serialization.
2. The code listed below works until the following conditions are met:
    a. The CopyObjectHierarchyTo is called recursively, and is iterating through an object which contains an instance of another object, and that object contains an instance of the parent reference.

I am trying to deep copy any object using this method, and avoid the StackOverflow exception. I understand that a StackOverflow is happening, and why, I need help understanding how to implement this programmatically to detect it before it happens.

I'm not sure if this is possible, but If I was able to see that an object housed in a reference, also contains an instance of the parent reference, that is basically what I would like to implement.

AKA Class A { Class B }   Where Class B Contains Class A

Thank you for the help.

```
    public static void CopyObjectHierarchyTo(this object sourceObject, object targetObject)
    {
        var objectMap = new Dictionary<object, object>();
        CopyObjectHierarchyTo(sourceObject, targetObject, objectMap);
    }

    private static void CopyObjectHierarchyTo(
        this object sourceObject,
        object targetObject,
        IDictionary<object, object> objectMap)
    {
        try
        {
            if (sourceObject == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(
                    "sourceObject",
                    string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Argument '{0} cannot be null!", "sourceObject"));
            }
            if (targetObject == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(
                    "targetObject",
                    string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Argument '{0} cannot be null!", "targetObject"));
            }
            if (objectMap == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(
                    "objectMap",
                    string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Argument '{0} cannot be null!", "objectMap"));
            }

            if (!objectMap.ContainsKey(sourceObject))
            {
                objectMap.Add(sourceObject, targetObject);
            }

            var targetType = targetObject.GetType();
            var targetProperties = targetType.GetProperties();
            var sourceType = sourceObject.GetType();

            foreach (var targetProp in targetProperties)
            {
                var sourceProp = sourceType.GetProperty(targetProp.Name);
                if (sourceProp == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var sourceValue = sourceProp.GetValue(sourceObject, null);

                if (sourceValue == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                object targetValue;
                if (objectMap.TryGetValue(sourceValue, out targetValue))
                {
                    targetProp.SetValue(targetObject, targetValue, null);
                    continue;
                }

                if (targetProp.PropertyType.IsValueType)
                {
                    CopyValueType(sourceObject, targetObject, sourceProp, targetProp);
                }
                else if (sourceProp.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    CopyString(sourceObject, targetObject, sourceProp, targetProp);
                }
                else if (sourceProp.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(
                    x =>
                    x.IsGenericType &&
                    x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)))
                {
                    if (!targetProp.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(
                        x =>
                        x.IsGenericType &&
                        x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)))
                    {
                        ThrowTypeMismatch(sourceProp.Name, sourceType, targetType);
                    }

                    CopyCollection(sourceObject, targetObject, sourceProp, targetProp, objectMap);
                }
                else
                {
                    targetValue = targetProp.GetValue(targetObject, null)
                                  ?? Activator.CreateInstance(targetProp.PropertyType);

                    if (targetProp.SetMethod == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    targetProp.SetValue(targetObject, targetValue, null);
                    sourceValue.CopyObjectHierarchyTo(targetValue, objectMap);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: To do this with reference types, you could use a Dictionary<Object, Object> and when you find an Object, look it up in the dictionary.  If it's not found, clone it, store the clone in the dictionary.  That way when the child object has a reference to the parent, when you look it up in the dictionary you get the parent clone, instead of a new clone.

Comment: Check out [this Github repo](https://github.com/Burtsev-Alexey/net-object-deep-copy) by Alexey Burtsev. It deep clones every object I throw at it. It might work for you too.